# Snow Leopard rubygems mysql2 and MAMP configuration for ruby on rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cmake, mamp

This is my config:

rails 2.3.5
ruby 1.8.7
gem 1.8.11
mamp 2.0.3 (which uses Mysql 5.5)

When creating a new rails project with mysql as the database, I get an error:

```
An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I believe this is because gems can't find the MAMP mysql files. So a tutorial says I should download the MAMP libraries and compile it without server so I can then point the gem to those files. The problem is that all tutorials use ./configure which no longer works for Mysql 5.5, instead you have to use cmake. This tutorial: http://blog.mirotin.net/35/mamp-1-9-5-mysql-5-5-9-and-ruby-mysql2 mentions a way to do it using cmake, but this command fails for me:

```
sudo port install cmake
```

can't find command port. So I tried with homebrew sudo brew install cmake which gives:

```
Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install'
```

So... What are my options? Rails and rubygems all seem to work, it's just pointing it to the MAMP mysql libraries that I'm having a problem with, I'm very new to rails (started yesterday). Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe I could accept any answers, the system told me I didn't have enough points or something. Maybe it told me that when I tried to vote for an answer. I will confess that I didn't know these rules, I was busy trying to get stuff to work. Also, about half the questions the answers where provided by me. Dont' get me wrong, I'm extremely appreciative of people who take time off their busy schedules to help other people, just didn't know this was a place where people count how many answers you've accepted. So I've accepted as many answers as I can, now will you help me?

Comment: Yes I do, but I updated all the packages via gems. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

In the end, installing cmake without sudo (who would have thought?) did work:

```
brew install cmake
```

Then I followed the instructions on this page:  http://blog.mirotin.net/35/mamp-1-9-5-mysql-5-5-9-and-ruby-mysql2

and everything seems to be working. Also for those of us new to ruby on rails, you might need to edit config/database.yml and add the socket directive, pointing to the MAMP socket:

socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Hope this helps someone else.

PS
I'll be sure to mark this as answered and give me lots of credit for it, thereby showing appreciation for myself so I can answer my future questions!

Comment: Glad you got it working and gave you a vote. Hope you appreciate yourself!